# Error de red tratando de comunicarse con el servidor

Tags: servidor, programación-móvil

Estoy desarrollando una aplicación móvil pero cuando agrego la seguridad GAM, al instalar la app en mi celular, aparece este error:

> Error de red tratando de comunicarse con el servidor (failed to connect to /10.0.2.2 (port 443) from 192.168.232.2 port (44494) after 5000ms).

por lo tanto no se abre la pantalla GAMSDLogin

Answer (score 0):

con la información que suministras es un poco complejo que se te pueda dar una correcta solución. Pero a nivel de red, debes verificar que la red del equipo móvil donde instalas la app tenga permisos para acceder al servidor, por lo que muestra el registro son dos subredes distintas, es posible que exista una restricción que no permita la comunicación. Dependiendo del equipo servidor, puedes hacer reenvío de puertos, apertura de puertos en el firewall, etc.